# Moving over tab spaces in ncurses

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am creating a basic text editor using ncurses.  It can display text fine, but navigating with arrow keys causes a problem when tabs are encountered.  Calling move(y, x) will freely move the cursor onto a tab space, where most text editors will jump to the next character.  Is there functionality within ncurses to jump over tab spaces or do I need to find a way to do it myself?

Comment: I think that if you want to support different tab sizes, you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it yourself: [`wmove`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_move.3x.html) moves to the given coordinates, ignoring the way characters are displayed on the screen.

If a destructive (filling with spaces) tab works for your application, then you could use [`waddch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Adding-characters):

> If *ch* is a tab, newline, carriage return or backspace, the
>   cursor is moved appropriately within the window:
>
> Tabs are considered to be at every eighth column.  The
>   tab  interval  may  be  altered by setting the `TABSIZE`
>   variable.

For an editor, you probably do not want that behavior (though it probably would be helpful to use the `TABSIZE` feature when displaying text).